# INSERT in MySQL doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with a MySQL request. Insertion doesn't work overnight. I don't know why.

```php
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die("Impossible de se connecter : ".mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('db');
$name = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM fruitandvegetable WHERE name='".mysql_real_escape_string(stripcslashes($_POST['name']))."'") or die('Erreur :'.mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($name) != 0) {
    $doublonName = "The name already exists";
}

$nombre = mysql_query("SELECT nombre FROM fruitandvegetable WHERE nombre='".mysql_real_escape_string(stripcslashes($_POST['nombre']))."'") or die('Erreur :'.mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($nombre) != 0) {
    $doublonNombre = "The number already exists";
} else {
    $quer1y = mysql_query("INSERT INTO fruitandvegetable VALUES('', '".$_POST['name']."', 'color', '$month', '$description', '".$_POST['nombre']."')");
}
```

thanks for your help.

Comment: Name the columns you want to insert into. And escape your user input

Comment: Please, [don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://us1.php.net/mysqli). [This article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide.[Prevent SQL Injection!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Why don't you use `mysql_error()` for the last query too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the column names:

```
$quer1y = mysql_query("INSERT INTO fruitandvegetable(column1,col2,col3,...) VALUES('', '".$_POST['name']."', 'color', '$month', '$description', '".$_POST['nombre']."')");
```

Plus, you should switch to [PDO](https://www.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/mysqli), as `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, and you *must* escape every user input or (better) use prepared statements to prevent [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection):

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db");
        $name = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT name FROM fruitandvegetable WHERE name='".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,stripcslashes($_POST['name']))."'")
        or die('Erreur :'.mysqli_error());

        if(mysqli_num_rows($name) != 0)
        {

        $doublonName = "The name already exists";

        }

        $nombre = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT nombre FROM fruitandvegetable WHERE nombre='".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,stripcslashes($_POST['nombre']))."'")
        or die('Erreur :'.mysqli_error());

        if(mysqli_num_rows($nombre) != 0)
        {

        $doublonNombre = "The number already exists";

        }         

        else  
        {   

        $quer1y = mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO fruitandvegetable VALUES('', '".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['name'])."', 'color', '".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$month)."', '".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$description)."', '".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['nombre'])."')"); 
        }
```

Comment: @JayBlanchard you're right, I updated my answer pointing out that :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but insertion does not work.

Comment: @mamaka add error_reporting(E_ALL); at the top of the document and see if it says something

Comment: @mamaka that's weird, error reporting should tell you what's wrong, not solve the problem... Anyways, I'm glad it works now :)